# Is there a way to replace an IP-Adress with a specific Name in Terminal?

Tags: ssh, terminal, ip, raspberry-pi

I just set up SSH on my Raspberry Pi B+ via a public-private-key, so I dont have to type in my Password every time I log into my Pi. Alas, I'm a lazy guy, so my question is:

Is there a way to set up my Terminal so I don't have to type in the IP-address, but a simple name for a device in my local network?

e.g. I'm using the command:

```
ssh monotom@192.168.178.x
```

instead I would love to use the command:

```
ssh monotom@pi
```

This may sound dumb, but I just like it as simple as possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using 'pi' instead of the IP requires that you have to setup a DNS server which will have the record that the name 'pi' is mapped to '192.168.178.x'.

Procedure of setting up DNS server can be found [here](http://linuxconfig.org/linux-dns-server-bind-configuration). You would need to add this new DNS server's IP address in list of your nameservers.

But as you mentioned that you are a lazy guy :), you can use:

```
history | grep monotom@
```

and then run:

```
!2344
```

where 2344 is the PID of the ssh command returned from 'history' command.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! That works pretty well :)

I'm already running a DNS server, but i didn't know the "history | grep" command. I also found out about the alias-command. Is there a reason why i should not just alias the ssh command?

Comment: Well I havent used alias command before. But using domain names to resolve IP addresses is a standard way.